# Display value from all file after merging in single csv

Tags: powershell, csv

I have 12 csv file which I am reading and merging it into single csv based on condition.

but after merging I am able to get only one record against each server as I used `$_.Group[0]`

below is my code

```
$allFiles = Import-Csv -Path  (Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Files\ -Filter '*.csv').FullName

$Final_Data = $allFiles | Group-Object VM | Select-Object Name,Count, @{n='Start';e={$_.Group[0].Start}},@{n='Host';e={$_.Group[0].Host}}, @{n='VMDiskLatency';e={$_.Group[0].VMDiskLatency}},@{n='Datastore';e={$_.Group[0].Datastore}} | Where-Object {$_.Count -ge 5} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Files\Final_Report.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

the data is like below in `$allFiles`

```
Start                 Host                  VMDiskLatency Datastore                                                                                                               
-----                 ----                  ------------- ---------                                                                                                               
1/11/2022 8:12:01 AM  t02.r                    94            MGT_1d59
1/11/2022 8:12:01 AM  z02.r                    81            Z_3255_325a                                                                             
1/11/2022 8:12:01 AM  n34.r                    108           EN_259b                                                                              
1/11/2022 8:12:01 AM  n35.r                    210           EN_259b                                                                                 
1/11/2022 8:12:01 AM  n37.r                    104           EN_f5bf
```

with my code I am getting final output like below

```
Name           Count    Start                Host           VMDiskLatency   Datastore
TN2AP           12  1/11/2022 8:12            n34.r            108           GEN_319c
TN1AP           12  1/11/2022 8:12            n35.r            210           GEN_259b
TN4AP           12  1/11/2022 8:12            n37.r            104           GEN_f5bf
H1SC            12  1/11/2022 8:12            n34.r            202           GEN_7a29
```

but the output I am looking for is like e.g giving for 1 server

```
Name           Count    Start                 Host          VMDiskLatency   Datastore
TN2AP           12  1/11/2022 8:12            n34.r            108           GEN_319c
                    1/11/2022 7:12                             201
                    1/11/2022 6:12                             182
                    1/11/2022 8:42                             103
                    1/11/2022 8:22                             66
                    1/11/2022 5:12                             99
                    1/11/2022 4:12                             541
                    1/11/2022 9:12                             100
                    1/11/2022 8:12                             209
                    1/11/2022 6:32                             115
                    1/11/2022 8:12                             78
                    1/11/2022 8:12                             62
```

The server in above came 12 times ( means in all the csv files) so, for **Start** and **VMDiskLatency**, there should be all the 12 entries.
If it was 6 then, all the 6 entries and so on..

Please let me know how can I do that.

Comment: Maybe you want `... |Group-Object VM |Select-Object Name,Count -ExpandProperty Group` instead?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: I will give this a try but I want all the values only for 2 columns as mentioned in the post. not for all. because all other columns will have same value across csv files

Comment: Then CSV is probably not the format you want. If you omit the column values from "consecutive" rows, then anyone can mess up your data set by simply re-ordering the rows.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen: got that. I can opt out from that. can display all the column values. but have to display all of them based on count. we are planning to schedule and send it via mail. so this is much we can do to prevent from any alternation of data for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to only attach the `Name` and `Count` values are set on the first object in each group, make two distinct selections - one for the first object *with* the property values, and one for the remaining objects where the property values are empty:

```
$allFiles |Group-Object VM |Where-Object {$_.Count -ge 5} |ForEach-Object {
  $name = $_.Name
  $count = $_.Count

  $first,$rest = $_.Group

  $first | Select-Object @{Name='Name';Expression={$name}},@{Name='Count';Expression={$count}},'Start','Host','VMDiskLatency','Datastore' 
  $rest | Select-Object @{Name='Name';Expression={""}},@{Name='Count';Expression={""}},'Start','Host','VMDiskLatency','Datastore' 
} | Export-Csv -Path "C:\Files\Final_Report.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

---

I'd personally recommend keeping the values attached to each object in the group, this way you can re-order the data without losing that context - and your expression becomes much simpler:

```
$allFiles |Group-Object VM |Where-Object {$_.Count -ge 5} |Select-Object Name,Count -Expand Group |Export-Csv -Path "C:\Files\Final_Report.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Tried your first solution. getting error
`At line:8 char:8
+   $rest  | Select-Object @{Name='Name';Expression={""},@{Name='Count' ...
+        ~
Missing '=' operator after key in hash literal.
At line:8 char:8
+   $rest  | Select-Object @{Name='Name';Expression={""},@{Name='Count' ...
+        ~
The hash literal was incomplete.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MissingEqualsInHashLiteral
`

Comment: @EmptyCoder Typo in property definitions, try again

Comment: How can I include other columns like Name and  Count?

Comment: @EmptyCoder I don't understand the question. Both examples include `Name` and `Count`

Comment: As per your first code, Name and Count value appears once then blank. I need same for Host and Datastore as well as mentioned in post. to do that what change I have to do?

Comment: @EmptyCoder Do the same as with Name and Count - store `$_.Group[0].Host` in a separate variable (although don't use `$host`), then use a calculated property to select an empty value, eg: `$hostGroup = $_.Group[0].Host; ... |Select ...,@{Name='Host';Expression={$hostGroup}}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240954/discussion-between-empty-coder-and-mathias-r-jessen).